# How to refer multiple identical worksheets on main sheet

Tags: excel

I have been attempting to create a main sheet to provide an overview for multiple product datasheets of the same format.

There are over 70 product datasheets in the one workbook, with each datasheet having over 50 parameters. This makes comparing between them by looking back and forth between each sheet very time consuming. e.g. of what a sheet may look like below:

| Parameter | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Item ID | 65198 |
| Voltage | 50V |
| Heated | Y |
| Cooled | N |
| Design temperature | 5-60°C |

I would like to refer to all datasheets on one 'main' sheet, and have the value for each parameter in its own column in order to easily compare such as in the example below.

| Item ID | Voltage | Heated | Cooled | Design Temperature |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 65198 | 50V | Y | N | 5-60°C |
| 51651 | 120V | N | N | 25°C |
| 89814 | 50V | Y | Y | -10-60°C |

I would like to refer to each sheet and cell value, listing each sheet as you go down the main sheets, e.g.

```
A2 = Prod65198!B2
A3 = Prod51651!B2
A4 = Prod89814!B2
```

The worksheet names are all different to one another, and I would rather not type them all out manually as there are so many. I was wondering if there was a way of quickly referring to sheets, perhaps by sheet index no. instead?

Answer (score 0):

Although Excel has got a function called `SHEET(reference)` which provides you with the sheet's index of the referenced cell, there does not seem to be any formula that can deal with this index.

Therefore, I would create a VBA macro to list all sheet names included in the Excel file and use `INDIRECT` and `INDEX` formulas to create the desired formula that can be dragged or copied. Check out this link: https://exceljet.net/formula/list-sheet-names-with-formula

However, if you already have to use VBA, you can also do the complete work in it.